# Generic Handler Jquery Post error

Tags: asp.net, jquery, generic-handler

I am getting this error (at the bottom) when I try to run this code using a generic handler

Jquery Code

```
 $.post("CheckUserName.ashx?username=Aaron902", 
                    function (result) { 
                        $('#username_availability_result').html('Name already exist!'); 

                        if (result == "exists") { 
                            $('#username_availability_result').html('Name already exist!'); 
                        } 
                        else { 
                            $('#username_availability_result').html('Still available'); 
                        } 

                    });
```

Handler Code

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
        { 
            string user_name = context.Request.QueryString["username"]; 
            string output = "here"; 
            output = CheckUserNameAvailability(user_name); 
            context.Response.Write(output); 
            context.Response.End(); 

        }
```

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request.   Please review the 
>   following specific parse error details and modify your source file 
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'Dating.CheckUserName'.
>
> Source Error:  Line 1: <%@ WebHandler Language="C#"
>   CodeBehind="CheckUserName.ashx.cs" class="Dating.CheckUserName" %>
>
> Source File: /CheckUserName.ashx    Line: 1
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237

Comment: Seems to be an error in the CheckUserName.ashx.cs, can you post the whole .cs file?
Did the project compile successfully?

Comment: The parser error says that the loaded assemblies do not have a class called `Dating.CheckUserName` in them. Is the `CheckUserName` class you specified in `CheckUserName.ashx.cs` contained in the `Dating` namespace? If this error is occurring on the production site, have you uploaded your newly built DLLs?

Comment: I'll post the full code when I get home.

Comment: It does compile fine and its not production

Comment: kinda stinks to have to do it this way but this comment box wont allow me to put the full code so you can view it here http://jsfiddle.net/8Fv98/ i know the code is not javascript but hey it works for what i am needing it for and that is just to show what my code is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix to my issue although I am not sure why it works this way and not the original way. All I did was remove the code behind file and put all the code that was there into the ashx file instead of having it in the `ashx.cs` file.

Of course I removed the directive `CodeBehind="CheckUserName.ashx.cs"`